# Highcharts credits link not working when exporting as PDF

Tags: highcharts

When I set the `credits.href` option for a Highcharts chart, everything works well in the browser. The credits text is a clickable link.

However, if the chart is exported as a PDF, the credits text is not a link.

Here is my code:

```
let exportOptions = {
  filename: filename, 
  fallbackToExportServer: false,
  type: 'application/pdf'          
};
let chartOptions= {
  credits: {
    enabled: true,
    href: "http://example.com",
    text: "TEMA-Q GmbH"
  }
}
chart.exportChartLocal(exportOptions, chartOptions);
```

Am I doing something wrong or are credit urls simply not exported to PDF?

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid that this functionality has not been implemented yet. I reported this idea on the Highcharts Github issue channel where you can follow and vote up this thread.

Link: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13594

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to know if I was doing something wrong.